# contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels in spite of having two levels

Tags: r, linear-regression, na, lm, categorical-data

I was trying out linear regression and observe that I get this error in spite of all my factor columns having at least two levels.

I tracked down to the column which is giving me this error and this is the summary of that column

```
> summary(df[,30])
    0     1  <NA>
31543    14     0

> unique(df[,30])
[1] 0 1
Levels: 0 1 <NA>
```

I have also eliminated all rows which have an NA value by doing the following

```
df = na.omit(df)
```

Please note that the NA above is an additional factor level I have added using the addNA function.

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT** : 
I have placed a reproducible example at my public share on http://aftabubuntu.cloudapp.net/ . Please download the reproduce.RDS file from here.

This is the code I'm using

```
df = readRDS('reproduce.RDS')
model = lm(formula = COL_101~.,data=traindf)
predict.lm(model, df[1:5,])
```

This is my output

```
> model = lm(formula = COL_101~.,data=df)
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Comment: You'll have to give us something reproducible; there's something else going on beyond what you've described here. I'll put a counterexample as an answer.

Comment: @Aaron I understand, let me try to create something you can reproduce

Comment: See this question on [how to make a great reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/210673) for suggestions.

Comment: OK, I peeked even though it was on another site. First, you've got 100 observations and 104 predictors, so this isn't even a sensible thing to do. Secondly, your summary lines aren't on the data set after running `na.omit`; that data set has only 13 observations. Please see the link above for suggestions on how to make a great reproducible example; this is something you would have noticed had you followed that advice.

Comment: @PepperBoy , do you remember how you solved this?

Comment: @Heuer, I think what was happening was that since, one of the factors in my training data had only very few instances, so upon doing a 10 fold cross validation, some train data sets were selected without any instances of that factor level, which basically means having just one factor level. You'lll have to increase the number of records for the minority factor level, or not do a 10-fold CV. Basically ensure that both factor levels are adequately represented.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite an answer, though possibly could be, if it turns out to demonstrate the issue. I can recreate data that looks like yours, but that works, as follows.

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x=addNA(rep(c(0,1), c(80,20))))
table(df$x)
##   0    1 <NA> 
##  80   20    0 
lm(y~x, data=df)
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)           x1  
##    0.007601     0.120172
```

Comment: I have placed a reproducible example in the public share mentioned in my edit. Please see my EDIT above.

Comment: For posterity, it's greatly preferred to not rely on data or information posted on other sites. Can you reduce it to the simplest possible case and post it here?